# What is the MLE if the variance is heteroskedasticity

Tags: statistics

The normal distribution of MLE is start $({x_1\ldots x_n})$ random sample from $N(u,\sigma^2)$

This family of distributions has two parameters: $\theta = (\mu, \sigma^2)$, so we maximize the likelihood, over both parameters simultaneously using logarithm...

I know this. but what if the normal distribution's  $({x_1\ldots x_n})$ random sample from $N(u,\sigma^2)$

That is the variance is heteroskedasticity...

My questions is that What is the MLE if variance change $\sigma^2$ to  $\sigma^2_i$.

$\sigma^2$ - homoscedasticity,

$\sigma^2_i$- variance is heteroskedasticity.

So $f\left(x ; u,\sigma _i^2\right)=\frac{e^{\frac{-(x-u)^2}{2 \sigma _i^2}}}{\sqrt{2 \pi } \sigma _i}$
I don't know.... How can I solved...

In the homoscedasticity, u hat is xbar and
sigma^2 hat is sigma^2/n.

Comment: Can you clafiry the difference between $\mu$ and $u$, that you both used for mean.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a negative sign in the exponent term? And what do you anderstand under $x$: a vector $(x1 \ldots x_n)$ or single sample $x_i$?

Comment: yes... you are right. exponent term is negative sign...but i don't using latex...